# Jmeter - How to send Cookie with the http request inside in the Header manager (not Cookie manager)

Tags: cookies, jmeter

For the purpose of my test, I need to send Cookie within the request like bellow.

[image]

If I try to do it with Header manager, cookies are ignored

[image]

I cant see them into the Request Headers where I need to see them.

[image]

Is there any way, how I can send Cokie into the reqest?
Note: Using Cokie managers is not working for me.

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

Are set up into the user.variables.

Using Jmeter 5.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at wrong place, the cookies are displayed under Request -> Request Body tabs of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

So you might want to check your HTTP Cookie Manager setup, it might be the case it's "working". If it doesn't - there might be a problem with the cookies returned by your application, i.e. it's expired, domain mismatch, path mismatch, etc.

In that case you need to raise a bug for your application or change the implementation of the HTTP Cookie Manager to something less restrictive i.e. `netscape`

[image]

You can see what's going on under the hood with the cookies by [increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the HTTP Cookie Manager.

Add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

and upon JMeter restart re-run your test and take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), you should see the incoming cookies and whether they're going to be added to the next request or not.

Comment: You were right. I was looking at the wrong place